# Insert variable value into ajax post data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, variables

I have created a form with textboxes and a dropdown menu, inside my code I've created a script which will be called when clicking "Send Form"

Lets say my field are : `firstName`, `lastName`, `country` (dropdown)

Here is the script:

```js
function f1() {
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "url": "https://api.TheSite.com/v2/applications/123456789/newJson.json",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "x-api-key": "123456789123456",
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    "processData": false,
    "data": "{\r\n  \"deployment\": {\r\n    \"revision\": \"string\",\r\n    \"changelog\": \"string\",\r\n    \"description\": \"string\",\r\n    \"user\": \"string\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert("The Form Was Sent");
  });
}
```

I would like to insert those 3 variables' values inside the "data" string like so:

```
"data": "{\r\n  \"deployment\": {\r\n    \"revision\": \`firstName
\",\r\n    \"changelog\": \"`lastName
```

and so on...

In the dropdown menu, I assume it will be displayed as an array. How do I include my variable inside?

Comment: ... why are you passing your data like that?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Hi Mike , 
this is the way i need to send my data , otherwise it wont be accepted,
so i only need to insert my variable to send them into the *data* string the will be sent alltogether .

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was wondering why, if you have to build your own JSON, you're bothering with `\r\n`...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan .
Thats right , so after each `\r\n` i need to insert my variable from the textbox above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an empty object and insert the data into it.
Next use `JSON.strigify()` to convert that into a `JSON blob` before you send it over to the server.

```
var data = {};
data.deployment = {};
data.deployment.revision = firstName;
data.deployment.changelog = lastName;

var settings = {
    ....,
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
};
```

Comment: Hi , 
I need to send the data as is , one variable everytime .
It means `"data": "{\r\n  \"deployment\": {\r\n    \"revision\": + 'firstName'`
Dont know what is the syntax  to add a variable

Comment: @EliasE Can you elaborate your question and the payload that you want to send.

Comment: @ Sushanth ,
Hi , 
This is the info i would like to send .
  `deployment : {
    revision    : firstName,
    changelog   : LastName,
    description : country,
    user        : user
  }`
the issue is the server accept a specific syntax (with `\n\r" string"`),when i tried to modify , it didnt reach the server ,

Comment: How does you `Model` data look like on your server ? Don't think it is mandatory to have `\r\n` as part of your payload.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery to perform your AJAX request, you should be aware that you can actually pass a native JavaScript object into the data portion of the request. You don't need to have it converted to a JSON string. If you want to, you can just stringify it.

You can actually establish default request options and then merge them with the data you want to request.

```js
var defaults = {
  url: 'https://api.TheSite.com/v2/applications/123456789/newJson.json',
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  headers: {
    'x-api-key': '123456789123456',
  },
  processData: false,
  async: true
};

function makeXhrRequest(config) {
  var xhrRequest = $.extend(true, defaults, config);

  // If you want to convert the request to a json String.
  //xhrRequest.data = JSON.stringify(data);

  $.ajax(xhrRequest).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
    alert("The Form was sent...");
  });
}

var $myForm = $('form[name="my-form"]');
makeXhrRequest({
  data : {
    deployment : {
      revision    : $myForm.find('input[name="firstname"]').val(),
      changelog   : $myForm.find('input[name="lastname"]').val(),
      description : 'string',
      user        : 'string'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi , @Mr. Polywhirl
Thanks for the your reply , after using your code , i got error 400 - bad request, i think it might be a syntax issue which the server expect to receive.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

this is the syntax that worked for me `+$("#firstName")[0].value+` and this is the code :

```
 "data":"{\r\n\deployment\: {\r\n revision\:"+"\""+$("#firstName")[0].value+"\","+"\r\n"
```